# Compare two array using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone I have an array

```
$dates = [2016-11-02,2016-11-05,2016-11-11,2016-11-15,2016-11-16]
```

in this I am getting all dates now I want to compare with `$currentdate (2016-12-16)` like this

```
if($dates <= $currentdate){
  echo "true"; 
} else{
  echo "false";
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about other answers, but if you are trying to validate all the dates, please use the below code... Should work :)

```
$isLess = false;
$currentDate = Carbon::now();

foreach($dates as $data) {
  if(Carbon::parse($date)->lte(currentDate)){
    $isLess = true;
    break;
  }
}

echo $isLess;
```

Let me know in the comments if you face any problem :)

Comment: I am having $dates[] now want to compare current date like this  $mytime =Carbon::now();
 $time= $mytime->toDateString();

Comment: @RahulSingh This will work for `$dates` as an array. and why do you want to convert `Carbon::now()` to a `DateString`? That will lead to a string comparision...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Laravel, you can do that with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
if (Carbon::now()->gte(Carbon::parse($oneDate))
```

Comment: I am having array of both dates and current date also how can i pass array in if (Carbon::parse($date) < Carbon::now()) thank you

Comment: Iterate over your array first, then compare.

Answer (score 0):

you can parse it to Carbon and use its comparison function

```
$date = Carbon::parse($date);
if($date->lte(Carbon::today())){
 // your code
}
```

Here 
    `lte()` means less than equal to

to know more about Comparison operator of carbon visit http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score -1):

In one line (albeit not the prettiest)

```
if (collect(collect($dates)->filter(function($date) use($currentDate) { return Carbon::parse($date)->lte($currentDate); }))->count > 0) {

}
```